# how to set value by id in react-select

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I use react-select.I have a number of react-select that change the values inside the state by handleChange.And finally they are stored somewhere(To simplify, I wrote a react-select).
So far no problem.

```
export const regionOptions = [
  { id: "1", value: "region 1", label: "region 1" },
  { id: "2", value: "region 2", label: "region 2" },
  { id: "3", value: "region 3", label: "region 3" },
  { id: "4", value: "region 4", label: "region 4" },
  { id: "5", value: "region 5", label: "region 5" },
  { id: "6", value: "region 6", label: "region 6" },
  { id: "7", value: "region 7", label: "region 7" },
  { id: "8", value: "region 8", label: "region 8" }
];
```

To edit the form, I want to set the react-select, but by ID.for example if State.region = 2 **react-select** **Result** = region2.
**tip:handleChange should not be changed**.
Here you can see my [codeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-darkness-7cq5n?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some modification in the render function in your codesandbox.
react-select accepts array of value and label pairs as options so you need to convert the region options to the data that react-select can accept correctly.

```
const tempOptions = regionOptions.map(option => ({
      value: option.id,
      label: option.label
    }));
```

This line is added to render function.

Comment: thank you.But I don't see any change in the MycodeSandbox

Comment: Here is the link.https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-northcutt-goc0z?file=/src/App.js:377-486

Comment: If possible, the amount of react-select will change with each change of region

Comment: Can you share examples for above one?

Comment: This is exactly my request.Take an region number (as an ID) and then react-select return the value

Comment: I did some modification. please check https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-dew-y5cwt?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1):

You can try this example:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

import Select from "react-select";

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      selectedOption: ''
    };
  }

  options = [
    { id: "1", value: "Spring", label: "Spring" },
    { id: "2", value: "Summer", label: "Summer" },
    { id: "3", value: "Autumn", label: "Autumn" },
    { id: "4", value: "Winter", label: "Winter" }
  ];

  handleChange = selectedOption => {
    this.setState({ selectedOption });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Select
          value={this.state.selectedOption}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          options={this.options}
        />
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            let summer = this.options.find(o => o.id === "2");
            this.setState({ selectedOption: summer });
          }}
        >
          Set Summer
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<Select
   options={regionOptions}
   getOptionValue={({ id }) => id}
 />
```